# '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, spyder

i am working on cnn code found in <://github.com/MesSem/CNNs-on-CHB-MIT/blob/master/CNN.py>  but i got this error { '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float' }

```
class EarlyStoppingByLossVal(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', value=0.00001, verbose=0, lower=True):
        super(keras.callbacks.Callback, self).__init__()
        print("val_loss\n")
        val_loss=model.evaluate(validation_data)
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.value = value
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.lower=lower

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        current = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if self.lower:
            if current < self.value:
                if self.verbose > 0:
                    print("Epoch %05d: early stopping THR" % epoch)
                self.model.stop_training = True
        else:
            if current > self.value:
                if self.verbose > 0:
                    print("Epoch %05d: early stopping THR" % epoch)
                self.model.stop_training = True
```

Comment: What are the values for `current` and `self.value` ?

Comment: current=non value and self.value=0.4021

Comment: And that's why you are getting an error! You need to add a condition to check to see if `current` is `none` and if so, define what you want it to be in that case (maybe 0?)